# Accumulate Field Values using Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have the follwing columns `KPI_PERIOD` and `KPI_VALUE` and want to achieve a new column named `KPI_Output` using Groovy.

The logic to achieve the `KPI_Output` is adding up the values of `KPI_Value`. In other words, for `Apr` the `KPI_Output` is the same as `KPI_Value`, as it's the first month. For May the `KPI_Output` value is `KPI_Value`s of `Apr` and `May`. For `Jun` the `KPI_Output` is `KPI_Value`s of `Apr`, `May`, and `June`. For `Jul` the `KPI_Output` value is `KPI_Value` of `Apr`, `May`, `Jun`, and `Jul` - and so on....

```
KPI_PERIOD  KPI_VALUE   KPI_Output 
Apr         33091       33091 
May         29685       62776
Jun         31042       93818
Jul         32807       126625
Aug         32782       159407
Sep         34952       194359
Oct         32448       226807
Nov         31515       258322
Dec         24639       282961
Jan         25155       308116
Feb         31320       339436
Mar         33091       372527
```

How can I achieve this using Groovy?

[image: Desired Results]

Answer (score 1):

Here You go:

```
def input = """KPI_PERIOD  KPI_VALUE
Apr 33091    
May 29685   
Jun 31042   
Jul 32807   
Aug 32782   
Sep 34952   
Oct 32448   
Nov 31515   
Dec 24639   
Jan 25155   
Feb 31320   
Mar 33091   
"""

def splitted = input.split('\n')[1..-1]
sum = 0
def transformed = splitted.collect { it.split(/\s+/)*.trim() }.inject([]) { res, curr ->
    sum += curr[1].toInteger()
    curr << sum.toString()
    res << curr    
}
println "KPI_PERIOD    KPI_VALUE   KPI_OUTPUT"
transformed.each { 
    println "${it[0].padLeft(10)} ${it[1].padLeft(12)} ${it[2].padLeft(12)}"
}
```

Hope it's all clear, if not feel free to ask.

Comment: Is that what You were looking for?

Comment: it looks like you started from the "desired output". I think that he wants to see running subtotals of the second column (33091, 29685, ...), not the third column (33091, 62776, ...). If I understand the problem correctly, the first two columns are given as input, and the third column is what the program is supposed to produce. There should not be a fourth column (as in your result).

Comment: This is how I usually work - I know input, 'desired output' and try to implement it that way. What You described is exactly how it's implemented. It has indeed 4 records for every row, but 3 columns are displayed. Have You tried it?

Comment: Yes, I did. Here is what I see in your results: first column: months, second column: values, third column: running subtotals of the values (expected output as given in the problem statement), fourth column(??): running subtotals of the subtotals (using the expected output as input(??)). I see four columns misaligned against three column headings.

Comment: I just thought that period with value is single column - misunderstanding. Corrected. Ok?

Comment: åbsolutely! You had the right technique, just the wrong "answer". All I was doing was trying to help. Now I can (and will) +1 you.

Comment: Aaah! Not used to having that sort of capability. I'll be sure to use it if I encounter a similar situation in the future.